# What rarity would the Staff of Defense be?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, published-adventures, lost-mine-of-phandelver

The Staff of Defense is described in the *Lost Mine of Phandelver* adventure (on p. 53), but the magic items in Appendix A have no rarity mentioned. The Staff of Defense, particularly, is unique to LMoP (i.e. it's not described in the DMG, or any other place I've found). It requires attunement. The description states:

> While holding the staff, you have a +1 bonus to your Armor Class.
>
> The staff has 10 charges, which are used to fuel the spells within it. With the staff in hand, you can use your action to cast one of the following spells from the staff if the spell is on your class’s spell list: mage armor (1 charge) or shield (2 charges). No components are required.
> The staff regains 1d6 + 4 expended charges each day at dawn. If you expend the staff’s last charge, roll a d20. On a 1, the staff shatters and is destroyed.

**What rarity would this item belong to?** (This is a question similar to homebrew "what rarity would my homebrew be", but the "homebrew" is actually official.)

This is an useful question for loot distribution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### D&D Beyond lists it as "rare"

The [description of the *staff of defense* on D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/staff-of-defense) says:

> *Staff, rare (requires attunement)*

The description of the *staff of defense* is only visible on D&D Beyond if you own the *Lost Mine of Phandelver* adventure there - or at least the item from it. However, [you can see its rarity in D&D Beyond's magic item listing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items?filter-type=0&filter-search=Staff%20of%20Defense) even if you don't own the adventure.

---

This fits with [Mike Mearls' (unofficial) statement on Twitter in January 2016](https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/692508618277658624):

> *in your opinion what rarity would the “staff of defence” pg 53 lost mines of phandelver*
>
> **I think I'd make it rare - getting *shield* a bunch of times is super useful.**

Answer (score 16):

## Mearls response

[Mike Mearls answers it in his twitter.](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/03/05/glasstaff-staff-of-defense/)

> I think I'd make it rare - getting shield a bunch of times is super useful.

## Adventurer's League Certificate

It also seems, from [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1omoTExpdh7cdiq9NnfVpf6-CnAkGRbA-FMIiNaZXpvg/edit#gid=1684901685) and from comments on [ENWorld](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?551227-Lost-Mines-of-Phandelver-certificates), [GiP](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?501590-Staff-of-Defense) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AdventurersLeague/comments/5rgz6z/can_i_give_myself_glasstaffs_staff_of_defense/), the item has a certificate indicating it's Rare as well. I don't own the certificate myself, so I can't confirm, but it seems to be the case.

So, from the closest we can get to official sources, the item is classified as **Rare**. The same appears to be true for Spider Staff, described in the last chapter and also unique to LMoP.

Comment: While mearls' tweets may be helpful, they aren't official.

Comment: That's why I mention "from the closest we can get to official sources". Although I do think V2Blast's DNDBeyond link is more official than that, so I'll probably be accepting his answer.

Comment: How is a Shield that you have to cast as an action, instead of reaction, useful?

Comment: @RonLugge That's Mearls response - he usually answers tweets, feel free to ask him. :P  - https://twitter.com/mikemearls/status/692508618277658624

Comment: @RonLugge For me, the main strength of SoD is actually the passive +1 AC. AC is hard to come. Most spellcasters can, in some way, profit from the fact they are casting spells (Wizard on Abj school, for example, would profit from casting shield), even if +5 AC is essentially the same as using Dodge. That said, my personal "power level rarity" would be Uncommon.

Comment: @RonLugge There's a [related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110471/can-one-cast-shield-from-the-staff-of-defense-as-a-reaction) on whether one can cast Shield as a reaction. My reading of Jeremy Crawford's response is that a DM could quite reasonably allow it and it was probably the intended functionality but he didn't want to go so far as to issue errata for the adventure.

Comment: @RonLugge Shield as an action helps in cases where you can't benefit from dodging, (e.g. you can't see your attacker, you have 0 speed, your attacker can't see you, your attacker is restrained, etc…) but you still want to increase the odds that you aren't hit over the next round. Concentrating on a powerful spell, trying to make sure you stay alive long-enough to *counterspell* a particularly potent enemy caster (without using up your reaction), or effectively blocking a narrow choke point to buy time for allies to do something else important are all examples that come readily to mind.